# Cannot figure out how to change selected cell in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const resultA1Notation = "D2"; // Change
  const range = e.range;
  const selectedValue = range.getValue();
  if (selectedValue === "UPGRADE") {
    let numberValue = range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
    if (numberValue !== "Free") {
      numberValue = numberValue.slice(0, -1); // Remove P
      const resultCell = sheet.getRange(resultA1Notation);
      resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() - numberValue);
      sheet.range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
      resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() + 15);
    }
  }
}
```

I can't get it to work through. I'm trying to modify these two lines:

```
sheet.range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() + 15);
```

I'm trying to get the script to offset the cell by -1, ex if it's B1 it would go to A1. Any help it appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the issue you are getting into? Also, can you share a copy of the sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to activate one left side cell for the current cell, when the selected cell value is `UPGRADE` and the value of one left side cell for the current selected cell is not `Free`.

  - As a sample situation, when the cell "B1" is selected, you want to select the cell "A1".
- You want to modify the following part in your script.

  ```
    sheet.range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
    resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() + 15);
  ```

In this case, in order to select the cell, I think that `activate` method can be used. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
sheet.range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() + 15);
```

#### To:

```
if (range.columnStart > 1) {
  range.offset(0, -1).activate();
}
```

- When the column "A" is selected, `range.offset(0, -1)` occurs an error. So I used the if statement of `if (range.columnStart > 1){}`.

#### Reference:

- [activate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate())

Comment: I tried experimenting with the provided script, and modified it to be "      range.offset(0, -3).activate();
      resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() + 15);" but then the second line that I'm trying to modify doesn't work.